# How to connect external JS scripts in index.html file in vite + react build?

Tags: reactjs, vite

When I try to plug in ready-made JS scripts in the index.html file, I get an error about a non-existent element. How can I plug such scripts into react application?
[image]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite + React</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>   
  <!-- Create one update function for each consent parameter -->
  <script>   
      document.querySelector('.accept-cookie-button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.cookie = "cookiesAccepted=true;max-age=31536000;path=/";
        document.querySelector('.cookies-policy-banner').remove();
      });

      let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + 'cookiesAccepted'.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
      if (matches && matches[1] === 'true') {
        document.querySelector('.cookies-policy-banner').remove();
      }

  </script>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Application Architecture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the elements in your page are generated by react, more specifically by this script

```
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
```

If you run code like this before react completed its rendering you will not find any elements:

```
document.querySelector('.accept-cookie-button')
```

the solutions is simple:
Run your code only after your main react component rendered. This is an information that only react has, and therefore you will need to use the react way to do it.
If you have a functional component this is done via a useEffect hook

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // code to run after render goes here
  });

  return (
    <div>whatever</div>
  );
}
```